# how i can do /var?section=value by .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

i want to make this url

```
site.com/var?section=value
```

example:

```
esite.com/PHP?section=articles
```

the php is varibale
and the php file is

```
file.php?lang=php&section=articles
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)\?section=(.*)$  file.php?lang=$1&section=$2  [NC,L]
```

Comment: these are optional flags used by .htaccess.  There's several others as well.  NC = not case sensitive, so if the url was Section, section or SECTION, the rule will continue to work.  L = if this rule matches, then stop processing rules at this point.  You might not require this, e.g. if you wanted to then translate file.php into something else, you'd probably leave the L flag off.